# Cordova camera plugin use with Ionic 3

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having a bit of trouble with Ionic. I'm trying to get the cordova camera plugin to work: I'm able to open the library, get the photos and crop them. However I can't figure out how to get them either into a variable for later use, or into an img source. here a bit of my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; 

import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Crop } from '@ionic-native/crop';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public translate: 
TranslateService, private imagePicker: ImagePicker, private cropService: Crop) {
  }

  uploadPhoto(){
    let options= {
      maximumImagesCount: 4,
    }
    this.photos = [new Array<string>()];
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options)
    .then((results) => {
      this.reduceImages(results).then(() => {
        console.log('all images cropped!!');
      });
    }, (err) => { console.log(err) });
  }

reduceImages(selected_pictures: any) : any{
    return selected_pictures.reduce((promise:any, item:any) => {
      return promise.then((result) => {
        return this.cropService.crop(item, {quality: 75})
                .then(cropped_image => this.photos.push(cropped_image));
      });
    }, Promise.resolve());
  }
}
```

Then here are the providers in my ngModules:

```
providers: [
StatusBar,
ImagePicker,
Camera,
Crop,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
```

And finally a bit of HTML:

```
   <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>
        Images
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content padding>
      <button (click)='uploadPhoto()' style="background-color: #000; color: 
    white; padding: 1em">Upload photo (on simulator only)</button>
      <br>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let photo of photos">
      <img src="{{photo}}" />
    </ion-card>

  </ion-content>
```

Comment: Your title suggests this is a camera plugin issue, but the camera plugin is working fine. That is - you are getting an image from the camera plugin and successfully passing it to the Crop plugin.  Have you tried logging the path received from the Crop plugin (cropped_image)?  Is this path reflected in the src tag when you debug ?

Comment: I'm sorry to have misled you! When I log the link I get a path starting with "file///" and then the path. Unfortunately when I use it as a img src nothing displays